# Looping an if statement?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to self teach myself python and I don't have much of an idea on what to do at certain parts.  What I am trying to get happen is that if the answer is NO it just keeps looping the question until the user finally answers YES and then the rest of the "game" will happen.

```
import random
import time

print("Think of a number from one to twenty. I will guess it.")
now = time.time()
questionTime = now + 2
while time.time() < questionTime:
    pass
question = input(" Yes or No? ")
if question.upper() == "NO":

elif question.upper() == "YES":
```

Comment: Can you explain what is currently happening in your code that is not behaving as expected? Include any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: You should read a tutorial or two http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: The [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html) is good too.

Comment: My problem was just at  the if statement I didn't know how to keep looping it if someone said no.  In this case if someone said no I just wanted it more or less to re-ask the question until they said yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the comments state, reading the documentation or navigating a tutorial would be great for you! I recommend [CodeCademy](https://www.codecademy.com/).

```
while True:
    doContinue = input('Would you like to start Y/N ?')
    if doContinue.lower() == 'y' or doContinue.lower() == 'yes':
        break
```

Comment: plus 1 for conciseness :). Although for *most* characters `str.lower()` is fine for caseless string comparison, I recommend using `str.casefold()` as it *always* works even with other kinds of characters.

Comment: I'll certainly look into CodeCademy, that's one I hadn't heard of before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
import time

print("Think of a number from one to twenty. I will guess it.")
now = time.time()
questionTime = now + 2
while time.time() < questionTime:
    pass

while 1:
    question = input(" Yes or No? ")
    if question.upper() == "YES":
        break
```

Comment: Why the `while time.time() < questionTime: pass` at all? And why `while 1` instead of just `while True`?

Answer (score 0):

Despite looking into some tutorials as suggested in the comments and going for a simpler example like TheLazyScripter presented, how about this one?

```
import random
import time

print("Think of a number from one to twenty. I will guess it.")
now = time.time()
questionTime = now + 2
while time.time() < questionTime: # Very CPU-intensive. Maybe use time.sleep(2)?
    pass
while True:
    number = random.randint(1, 20)
    question = input("Is it " + str(number) + "? - Yes or No? ")
    if question.upper() == "NO":
        continue
    elif question.upper() == "YES":
        break
```